# jQuery Tooltip Showing Tabs But Not Newlines?

Tags: jquery, tooltip, newline

I'm using the following jQuery code to display tooltips in a .NET web application:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Tooltip only Text
  $('.masterTooltip').hover(function () {
    // Hover over code
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
    $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
    .text(title)
    .appendTo('body')
    .fadeIn('slow');
  }, function () {
    // Hover out code
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
    $('.tooltip').remove();
  }).click(function (e) {
    var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
    var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
    $('.tooltip')
    .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
  });
});
```

The data being displayed with show tabs when I use char(9) in the SQL record but why won't it show newlines when I use char(10) + char(13)?

[image: JQuery Tooltip]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither tab (`\t`) nor new line (`\n`) are recognized HTML characters.

For tab you can use: `&emsp;` (you could also use: `&#9;`)

For new line, you need to use `<br/>` (replace your `\n` char with `<br/>`)

or you can put your pre-formatted text inside html [pre tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp):